# Docker port rewrite

Tags: docker

I used docker for wordpress like this:
Create volume containers:

```
$ docker create -v /home/juanda/project/bbdd:/var/lib/mysql --name bbdd ubuntu /bin/true

$ docker create -v /home/juanda/project/web:/var/www/html --name web ubuntu /bin/true
```

Mysql container:

```
$ docker run --volumes-from bbdd --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="xxxx" -d mysql
```

Apache, php and wordpress container:

```
$ docker run --volumes-from web --name apache --link mysql:mysql -d -p 5555:80 wordpress
```

I installed and ran everything ok. If I remove apache container (stop and rm) and I launch it awain in another port (8080 instead of 5555), **it rewrites url in navigator to 5555 and I get a connection error**. Any idea?